# Twitter API XSS work around

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, web

When I'm looking at [Spring Source site](http://www.springsource.org/) I see js widget which requests

http://search.twitter.com/search.json

using AJAX.

How do they work around cross-domain security issue?

Comment: Are GET requests are subject to the same XSS constraints?  I didn't think so.

Comment: They are using JSONP, this is called CORS not XSS btw.

Comment: @Esailija, I'm sorry, but what is the difference between CORS and XSS?

Comment: XSS is an unwanted vulnerability while CORS is deliberate and controlled

Comment: this is not JSONP - http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=failwhale, there's no function padding around the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSONP](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/twitter-jsonjsonp-api-url.html) is one way to work around the security limitation.